# How to clean the fields in my contact form? In PHP

Tags: php, sendmail

I'm creating a contact form in PHP to send data to emailand I want to clear the fields automatically when pressing "send".

This is my code: sendmail.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$correo= $_POST['correo'];
$asunto=$_POST['asunto'];
$texto=$_POST['texta'];

$para = 'email@email.com';
$header .= 'From: ' . $correo;
$mensaje ="Nombre del remitente: " . $nombre . 
          "\n \n Mensaje enviado: " . $texto . 
          "\n \n Enviado el dia: " . date('d/m/Y');


mail($para, $asunto, utf8_decode($mensaje), $header);

echo 'mensaje enviado correctamente';

?>
```

This is the contact form in html

```
<form action="php/sendmail.php" method="post" class="contact-form">
  <div class="form-group">                
    <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">                
    <input id="correo" name="correo" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Introduce tu correo" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">                
    <input  id="asunto" name="asunto"  type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Asunto" required>
  </div>              
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="texta" name="texta" class="form-control" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" data-text="SEND" class="button button-default"><span>SEND</span></button>
</form>
```

Comment: In what way are they currently *not* cleared?  If the POST action is taking the user to a different page then the inputs won't even be there.  Are they still populated when the user returns to this page?  Can you describe the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: It's a very bad habbit - naming variables in your native language. Anyway, you can't clear the fields using PHP, because PHP has no idea about the form, the form in on the clients machine, PHP is on the server. I presume your form is being sent via ajax, otherwise it would clear itself after page refresh. You can achieve the desired behavior using javascript.

Comment: Does the email actually get sent? Do you see the `echo 'mensaje enviado correctamente';` on the browser?

Comment: If you dont see `mensaje enviado correctamente` on the browser I would suggest that the `sendmail.php` is crashing and with this set `error_reporting(0);` you will never know. *another bad habit to get into* Add error reporting back into your script at the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: The message is sent and if mail arrives and when it does I put a blank page with the message 'message sent successfully'.

If I do it with javascript what is what and where should I place?  Excuse my mistakes, I'm starting in this world

Comment: Forget the `javascript` idea, too complex for you at the moment